# Is there a way to emulate "Enter" key press in opera mini?

Tags: javascript, opera-mini

after reading some documentation I understand that Opera mini does not support key press events. 
I'm curious about one thing though: When entering text we use the phone's text input method, and end up by pressing "OK" one way or another. Is there any way (even browser specific) to emulate a keydown listener that would test for the 13 keyCode ?

I'm using the simplest method to catch the event (I know it's basic, it's for a super simple project)

```
<input type="text" id="query" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('btnSearch').click()" />
```

Note: I'm using Opera mini 4.4 but I'll accept tricks for any version out of curiosity :)

**edit**: Something is definitely happening when the listener is present, Opera does some "processing" which means it's executing client code. The processing disappears if I remove the listener. Still, I can't get it to execute anything. It just processes and goes back to the top of the page

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Keydown` is [unsupported DOM event](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-mini-and-javascript/#unsupporteddom) in Opera Mini. It will be better to change your app using `change` event, but enter key do not fire change event. You can try `document.createEvent` and `initKeyboardEvent` methods, but IMHO for `keydown` it will not work also.

Comment: Thanks! Will try to fiddle with what you mention out of curiosity